# Docker build of windows image hangs during RUN step

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cpu-usage

Docker image build lasts forever and CPU usage is 0%.

**Build command:**

```
docker build --no-cache --progress=plain -t harness/err_tracking_build_ex:latest .
```

**The Dockerfile content:**

```
# escape=`
# Select the required Windows Server Release:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2

# Restore the default Windows shell for correct batch processing.
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

RUN `
    # Download the Build Tools bootstrapper.
    curl -SL --output vs_buildtools.exe https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe `
    `
    # Install Build Tools with the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.AzureBuildTools workload, excluding workloads and components with known issues.
    && (start /w vs.exe --norestart --wait --quiet --nocache `
        --installPath "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools" `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.MSM `
        --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools `
        || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0) `
    `
    # Cleanup
    && del /q vs_buildtools.exe
ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\Common7\\Tools\\VsDevCmd.bat", "&&", "powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

**Log:**

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/4 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2
 ---> 2252ecd481b9
Step 2/4 : SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 48199772975d
Step 3/4 : RUN curl -SL --output vs_buildtools.exe https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_buildtools.exe && (start /w vs.exe --norestart --wait --quiet --nocache --installPath "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools" --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.BuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools           --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.MSM --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0) && del /q vs_buildtools.exe
 ---> Running in a7068b95b75e
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 1611k  100 1611k    0     0  1611k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 8668k
```

(Stuck in the last row forever)

I also tried without --no-cache but it didn't help.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Remove `--quiet` and you may be able to see some logs.

Comment: the `--ouput` of your curl download is named `vs_buildtools.exe`, yet in the next step you are calling `vs.exe`

Comment: You are correct!
Now it works fine!
Thanks!